# What is the symbol that shows word blending called?

Tags: symbols, blending

[image]

What is the name of this symbol that I marked in red? What is it's Unicode value?

Comment: To the user who voted to close the question for lack of research. Are you off your head? Unless you know the actual name of the symbol how is anyone supposed to know where to look? The "experts" are the users *replying* not doing the asking.  This is not something which you Google, or look up in a dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Since the OP suspected that it might be a Unicode character, he could have done what I did: look in the relevant character map.

Comment: Well it took me ages to find it, without copying and pasting the symbol, there are also many different categories, and lists, maybe it's easy for someone who works in that field. Do we have any guarantee that Suragh is a programmer? Maybe he is, maybe he isn't. I still say this answer cannot be Googled in a couple of minutes, unless you already know its name, or which Unicode category it pertains to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Network profile: "Student of Android and iOS programming." I suspect that he did look in the character maps, but couldn't find it. Never mind.

Comment: Ah, interesting they're called *maps*, why are they called that? I should have noticed. Will file away for future reference, thanks @Mick

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Unicode is a collection of related things: a set of characters, a set of algorithms for dealing with characters (e.g. converting from lowercase to uppercase, converting to different canonical formats, collation), and a standardized **mapping** from numbers (called *codepoints*) to characters. The Unicode character set is usually presented together with the corresponding codepoints (e.g. as a set of mappings), hence a "map".

Comment: For future reference, there are tools that you can use to search the Unicode character set by character shape. [Here is one such tool](http://shapecatcher.com/); it finds the "undertie" Mick mentions, as well as several other similar types of musical slurs, like Mari-Lou mentions.

Comment: Great tool, @CodyGray. I'm bookmarking that one.

Comment: Also handy - http://ilg.usc.es/ipa-chart/keyboard/

Comment: @PhilSweet, I had searched on some other IPA charts but this one makes it easy to find (and type).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called an [*undertie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(typography)#Undertie):

> **Undertie**
>
> The undertie is used to represent linking (absence of a break) in the IPA. For example it is used to indicate liaison (e.g. /vuz‿ave/).
>
> On computers, the character used is U+203F ‿ UNDERTIE. This is a spacing character, not to be confused with the alternative (below-letter) form of the ligature tie (a͜b U+035C ͜ COMBINING DOUBLE BREVE BELOW), which is a combining character.

Wikipedia

Comment: Merry Christmas" You beat me to it, I had only just found out its phonetic name. In music the same symbol (it looks identical) is called a **slur** [A slur is a symbol in Western musical notation indicating that the notes it embraces are to be played without separation, i.e. with legato articulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slur_(music))

Comment: @Mari-LouA And a Merry Christmas to you! I didn't know the term, but I do know my way around the Unicode character set. Well... that's my story, and I'm sticking to it. ;-)