# Is there a name for this symbol: |

Tags: symbols

The symbol (or whatever classifies it): |

Comment: It is just called a [*vertical bar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) (or [*vertical line*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7c/index.htm)).

Comment: Isn't it the vertical bar?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar

Comment: No, that's a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Pipe)

Comment: Someone pasted this link http://shapecatcher.com on [another recent question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365107/what-is-the-symbol-that-shows-word-blending-called#comment851387_365107)

Comment: The vertical bar gets much use in mathematics: || means Or: |x| means norm or absolute value of x; a|b means a divides b; and {x in S | ...} means the subset of S whose elements meet the conditions to the right of the vertical bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its name is ***pipe*** or ***bar***. You can see the name of other special characters on the keyboard [here](http://coolefriend.com/productivity/know-names-of-symbols-in-your-computer-keyboard/).

Answer (score 1):

It’s called  ***pipe*** or ***vertical bar***.

You can find this detail [here](http://www.computerhope.com/keys.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It's generically called a [bar](https://www.englishforums.com/content/resources/did-you-know-all-the-computer-keyboards-names-in-english.htm).

Some characters take special meaning in certain contexts. For instance /./ is traditionally called a *period*, but the use of *dot* came into fashion for websites. Similarly, the term *pipe* came into fashion because the action it represents in terminal based programming, in which the output of one command is "piped" to the input of another. In different programming contexts it would not be a pipe, but, for instance, logical or. In any context it is a bar.